# Simple MySQL WHERE query not using Index

Tags: mysql, indexing

---

**Quick Answer:** Query condition needs to be same type as column to use index. I was trying to search a CHAR column with a numeric condition.

---

I have a table with 15 million rows. I have a column called 'ticket' that can occur multiple times but it wouldn't occur very many times . . . probably less than 10. I have created an index on this column but the explain command says that when I am using a simple 'WHERE ticket =' query that it is not using the index. Obviously this confuses me as I am asking a question here.

```
CREATE TABLE company1.rTable (
  `aDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `fromD` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `pNo` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticket` char(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `r` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `line` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `nNum` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `pKey` char(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modNum` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dnum` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `rdNum` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `pType` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lNum` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lineAmount` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount1` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount2` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount3` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount4` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount5` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount6` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount7` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount8` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount9` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount10` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tType` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lineB` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lineD` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lineP` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lineI` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lineC` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lineW` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lineR` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lineM` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `rADate` (`aDate`),
  KEY `rTType` (`tType`),
  KEY `rTicket` (`ticket`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

My query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   company1.rTable
WHERE  ticket = 3478421;
```

Maybe there is a way to change the query to use the index? I tried things like 'AND ticket > . . .' as a guess but that didn't help.

Comment: sometimes mysql will decide it's easier to just do a table scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ticket` is a char column and you are using number condition (3478421).

Comment: Thank you . . . I neither noticed or thought of that as mattering. I will pay attention to that in the future.